# What is the correct way of visiting Abkhazia without violating Georgian laws?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, georgia-country, disputed-territories, abkhazia

[Abkhazia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazia) is a partially recognized state that forms a part of Georgia. I would like to visit both Abkhazia and Georgia on a single trip. What is the right sequence (if any) of doing so?

For example I'm aware that Serbia requires people to get stamped in Serbia before visiting Kosovo, so perhaps there's something similar for Abkhazia.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **only** legal way to enter Abkhazia is from the territory of [Zugdidi Municipality](https://www.google.ru/maps/place/Zugdidi,+Georgia/@42.4792573,41.8503083,10.75z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x405c24e8b5416e97:0x554b6500e78b56d8!8m2!3d42.5091391!4d41.866992). There is no other way!

[According to Georgian law on Occupied Territories](https://matsne.gov.ge/en/document/view/19132?publication=6)
 (Article 4) in all other cases you will inevitably violate the law and fall under criminal responsibility by Georgian laws.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91118/can-i-travel-to-abkhazia-on-a-russian-visa for an alternative sequence that, while not compliant with Georgian law, also seems to work just fine.

Comment: The question here was how to visit Abkhazia legally, not how to visit at all hazards incl violating the law. For the latter use the question you point out