# Can you enter South Ossetia from Georgia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, georgia-country, disputed-territories, south-ossetia

As the title says, is it possible to enter South Ossetia from Georgia or do you have to enter from Russia? 
Btw, I'm from Denmark if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Abkhazia, South Ossetia **cannot** be entered from Georgia - the border officers won't let you pass.

So you have to enter from Russia, which is illegal by Georgian law. However, passports aren't stamped (even when exiting and re-entering Russia), so unless you run your mouth to the Georgians, there's absolutely no way for them to know.

Comment: The second paragraph should start with "So you have to enter from Russia [...]"

Answer (score -1):

My [previous answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/69314/42757) about Abkhazia is valid for South Ossetia as well.

As [stated](http://belgium.mfa.gov.ge/index.php?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=1227) by the Georgian Ministry of Foreign Affairs, the only legal way to get to former South Ossetia from Georgian territory is from the [Gori Municipality](https://www.google.com.ua/maps/place/Gori,+Georgia/@41.9808527,44.0555438,12.48z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x40449ea06faca507:0xefe8902458a375a1!8m2!3d41.9854144!4d44.108411).

Comment: Downvote - the Q answer whether it's **possible** to enter from Georgia, and it is **not**

Comment: Oops, didn't notice :)